# Little-oh notation for two logarithmic functions?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime, complexity-theory, proof, little-o

I have the following function (with the natural log and log base 2):

[image]

and I am trying to prove the validity of this statement. I believe it is true. All logarithms are asymptotically equivalent to each other. I am trying to write the formal proof for this and find a [image] and [image] that would make my argument true. I use the little-oh definition:

```
0 =< f(n) < g(n)

0 =< lg(n) < ln(n^2)

0 =< lg(n) < 2 ln(n)
```

This is about as far as I got but I am having trouble completing the proof and finding a `c` and `n_0` value. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that `log_2(n) ∈ o(ln(n^2))`. To directly see it you might consider the limit of `log_2(n)/ln(n^2)` as n goes to infinity which corresponds to `2/ln(2) ∈ (0, ∞)`.  Thus, `log_2(n) ∈ Θ(ln(n^2))`.
This means that you can find two constants `c₁` and `c₂` and an input size `n₀` such that `c₁⋅log_2(n) ≤ ln(n^2) ≤ c₂⋅log_2(n)` for all `n ≥ n₀`